# What does logging in a user do?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In Firebase, I get that the `authUser(..)` function verifies a email and password, but does it do anything else aside from that? Specifically, does it create some sort of *active session* for the user? Because as far as I know there is no method in the API to get the *logged in user* so is there any other purpose for `authUser(..)` besides to verify an email and password?

Comment: Firebase has no `authData()` method. It'll probably be a lot easier if you show the code you've tried (that'll also tell us what language you're using) and what problem you're running into.

Comment: excuse me, I meant `authUser`. I'll change it. I'm using swift.

Comment: `ref.authData` gets you the currently authenticated user. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication. Unless you can clarify further with a lot more code and purpose, it'll be impossible to help.

Comment: so the `authData` object returned in the completion block *is* the currently authenticated user?

Comment: Yes. But I was actually referring to `if (ref.authData) {`, which is synchronous so doesn't have a completion block.